# Getting props undefined in the component when using render props with React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement password reset and currently when the user clicks the link sent to the email(embedded with token and userId), he's redirected to the update password page. So, there in `UpdatePassword` component, I'm getting props undefined. Here's the code.

In `App.js`

```js
  <Route
    path="/update-password"
    render={({ match }) => (
      <UpdatePassword
        userId={match.params.userId}
        token={match.params.token}
      />
    )}
  />
```

`UpdatePassword` is a simple component with just two input fields:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"

class UpdatePassword extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
      isSubmitted: false
    }
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Update your password</h2>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
            <input
              className="input"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              type="email"
              placeholder="Enter new password"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </span>
            <span className="icon is-small is-right">
              <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
            <input
              className="input"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="confirmPassword"
              value={this.state.confirmPassword}
              type="email"
              placeholder="Confirm password"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </span>
            <span className="icon is-small is-right">
              <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="button is-success">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default UpdatePassword
```

Backend route is `router.post("/receive_new_password/:userId/:token", emailController.reveiveNewPassword)`

Comment: where you have "undefned" at console.log(this.props) ?

Comment: Yes. Also, in the dev tools.Well, `this.props` is just returning an object with `userId` and `token` as undefined.

Comment: try with this.props.route.userId ?

Comment: try to pass simple string prop to UpdatePassword from "App.js" to test it. add look what is in the "console.log(this)"

Comment: @sv12 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined`

Comment: @UladzislauUlasenka you mean without render prop?

Comment: i tried this `path="/update-password/:userId/:token"` and it's working, but idk it's the correct way or not

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with `match`. `params` can be `undefined`. Try this:

```
<Route
    path="/update-password"
    render={(prop1, prop2) => {
    const { match } = prop1; 
    console.log(prop1, prop2, match);
    return (
      <UpdatePassword
        userId={match.params.userId}
        token={match.params.token}
      />
    )}
  />
```

Comment: i'm getting `match` but `params` undefined.

Comment: i tried this `path="/update-password/:userId/:token"` and it's working, but idk it's the correct way or not

Comment: query params is the right way to share userId, but not for the token. It's better to store token in cookie or session, for example

Comment: It's a one time token btw. It's been created using the user's hashed password and the createdAt value.